# Obtener y copiar archivo .db de SQLite en Android mediante ADB

Tags: android, adb

Tengo una aplicación en `android` que hace uso de la clase `SQLiteOpenHelper` para trabajar una base de datos local con 3 simples tablas, para obtener el archivo `MY_DATABASE.db` hago uso de comandos mediante el `ADB` de la siguiente forma:

```
$ adb shell
shell@device:/ $ run-as com.my.package
shell@device:/data/data/com.my.package $ cp databases/MY_DATABASE /sdcard/MY_DATABASE.db
shell@device:/data/data/com.my.package $ exit
shell@device:/ $ exit
adb pull /sdcard/MY_DATABASE.db
```

Mi problema es que dichos comandos no funcionan en todos los dispositivos que he probado:

> Moto E (con root y sin este) **FUNCIONA** 
>   Moto G (con root y sin este) **FUNCIONA** 
>   Nexus 5x (con root y sin este) **NO FUNCIONA** 
>   Samsung J1 (sin root) **NO FUNCIONA** 
>   Samsung J2 (sin root) **NO FUNCIONA** 
>   Huawei (sin root) **NO FUNCIONA**

**¿Qué puedo hacer para que los comandos me funcionen en cualquier dispositivo?**

Logré hacer esto sin ningún problema en todos los dispositivos mencionados arriba mediante esta función:

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "copying...");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "copied");
}

String strSrc = "/data/data/com.my.package/databases/MY_DATABASE"
String strDst = "/sdcard/MY_DATABASE.db";

File fSrc = new File(strSrc);
File fDst = new File(strDst);

try{
    copy(fSrc, fDst);
}catch(IOException e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

Sin embargo quiero poder realizar este proceso mediante el `ADB`

Comment: Entiendo que lo quieres es porque tu app, obtenga la base de datos de la memoria externa? no seria mejor hacer que la App se pueda mover a la SDCard, así todo su raiz de archivos estarán allí. Para realizar un sistema de backup, yo lo haría algo similar a SQLDump

Comment: ¿Algún avance en este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que el terminal esté rooteado o no es indiferente al usar el comando `run-as`. Si quieres hacer uso de los privilegios especiales del usuario `root` para realizar la copia debes teclear primero el comando `su` (y aceptar elevar los permisos en tu gestor de root) y posteriormente hacer el `cp` para copiar las bases de datos.

No todos los terminales soportan `run-as` o les funciona correctamente. He visto en foros en los que no estaba disponible o tenía permisos incorrectos y han tenido que remontar como `rw` el sistema de archivos `/system` y ajustar los permisos correctamente con `chmod 4750 /system/bin/run-as` ([ver este ejemplo](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373#c41)).

En otros casos puedes tener problemas con los permisos de la aplicación. Como `run-as` te otorga exactamente los mismos permisos de una aplicación en particular, es probable que dicha aplicación no tenga permisos para escribir en la microSD, por lo que te dará permiso denegado al copiar en `/sdcard`.

En versiones modernas de Android las aplicaciones no pueden escribir en el raíz de la microSD sin ayuda de la aplicación de sistema `Documentos` (y en muchos terminales ésta viene inhabilitada por defecto).

Debes ponerme exactamente el mensaje de error que te impide usar `run-as` para determinar en qué caso te encuentras. Un simple **FUNCIONA** o **NO FUNCIONA** no ayuda en la resolución de tu problema.